# How can i get all class name by regex

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

```
let string = `<img class="img-fluid big-img logo">
<a class="link link-red link-2">link</a>`;
```

I want to get all the class name by regex not other way

I want to put them inside an array like:

```
let allClass = ["img-fluid", "big-img", "logo", "link",......];
```

Comment: we expect you have done some research and write some code.

Comment: `DOMParser` + `.classList`

Comment: I tried it with regex but my pattern was not working as I expected.  I know how to do it by using dom function but I want to do this as a string and want to get class name by regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could do something like this:

```
var pattern = /class="([^"]+)"/g;
var classes = [];

[...string.matchAll(pattern)].
    forEach(
        match => classes = classes.concat( (match[1].split(" ")) )
    );

console.log(classes); // ["img-fluid", "big-img", "logo", "link", "link-red", "link-2"]
```

Effectively here we have a regex that matches `class="..."` and captures everything inside of the quotes. Then we run `matchAll` with the addition of the *spread operator* (`...`) so that it produces an array we can iterate over with `forEach`.

Then we simply loop over the array, split the captured string into an array and merge with the `classes` array

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution but I don't know how efficient it is but it works

```
let regex = /class="(?:([\w+\-])(?:\s|")?){1,}/g;
    let collectClass = [];
    string.match(regex).forEach(item => {    item.replace(`class=`, "").replace(`"`, "").split(" ").forEach(item => collectClass.push(item))    })
    allClass = collectClasses.filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);
```